# Problem with sql in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I wanted to get the sql query like `SELECT numbers FROM table ORDER BY numbers+0;` in zend framework.

I am new to zend. Can anyone please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: sure .. you are welcome. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this:

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()->from('table','numbers')->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('numbers+0'));
    var_dump($select->assemble());

    //outputs: 
    //string 'SELECT `table`.`numbers` FROM `table` ORDER BY numbers+0' (length=56)
```

`new Zend_Db_Expr` is needed because without it, ZF will add 'ASC' to your query:

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()->from('table','numbers')->order('numbers+0');
    var_dump($select->assemble());

    //outputs:
    //string 'SELECT `table`.`numbers` FROM `table` ORDER BY `numbers+0` ASC' (length=62)
```

Hope this helps.